# What it does 'declare' in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Taking a brief look of `electron-react-boilerplate` repository in [github](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate.git) I realized a code in javascript that couldn't understand.

```
declare module "flow-bin" {
  declare module.exports: string;
}
```

What it does **declare**?, it's part of ES6, ES7? I've searching in the way though can't find something about it. Anyone can give me some information about what it mean?

Comment: It's http://www.typescriptlang.org

Comment: Strange.  Looks like TypeScript code, but the file the OP references has a .js extension and TS is not referenced in the project's `project.json` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is [typescript's](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html) grammar. Use to

> ambient module declaration

Typescript use `declare` to do a **strict type checking**.Then make a grammar check before compile.For eg.

```
declare var jQuery: (string) => any;

jQuery('#foo');
```

The above code declare that the jQuery accept a string parameter.